# How to append data to existing file in HDFS using Java API?

Tags: java, hadoop

I am using `hadoop` version 2.6.0 and trying to append data to existing file in HDFS but seem that it doesn't work for me. Here's my method to write into HDFS using `FileSystem.Append` function.

```
HdfsIO hdfsIO = new HdfsIO(hdfsCoreSite,hdfsSite);
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(hdfsIO.getConfiguration());
FSDataOutputStream out = fs.append(new Path("/test_dir_10/append_data_to_this_file.txt"));
out.writeUTF("Append demo...");
fs.close();
```

Write() and create() functions work well but append() function. 
I got this error :

> Failed to close file /test_dir_10/append_data_to_this_file.txt. Lease
>   recovery is in progress. Try again later.

I also added this property to hdsf-site.xml

```
<property> 
    <name>dfs.support.append</name>
    <value>true</value> 
</property>
```

So anyone have an idea what I'm missing or doing wrong? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by running on file system

```
hadoop dfs -setrep -R -w 2 /
```